# Hacer una correcta consulta de dos tablas

Tags: laravel-5, orm, eloquent

Estoy teniendo un problema con una consulta en Laravel donde se relacionan dos tablas: `Empleados` y `Emergencias` en una relacion 1:N. Según yo, tengo bien las relaciones en mis modelos que son los siguientes.

**Empleado**

```
    class Empleado extends Model
    {
       use SoftDeletes; 

       protected $table    = 'empleados';
       protected $fillable = ['id', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'fechaNac', 'telefono', 'celular', 
                               'celularEmp', 'email', 'emailEmp','color', 'departamento',
                               'puesto', 'sueldo];
       protected $dates    = ['deleted_at'];
       public $timestamps  = true;

       public function emergencias()
       {
          return $this->hasMany('Valach\Emergencia', 'empleado_id', 'id');
       }

       public static function getEmpleados()
       {
          return DB::table('empleados')
                   ->leftJoin('emergencias', 'empleados.id', '=', 'emergencias.empleado_id')
                   ->get();
       }
    }
```

**Emergencia**

```
    class Emergencia extends Model
    {
       protected $table      = 'emergencias';
       protected $primaryKey = 'empleado_id';
       protected $fillable   = ['empleado_id', 'tel', 'cel', 'contacto'];
       public $timestamps    = false;

       public function empleado()
       {
          return $this->belongsTo('Valach\Empleado');
       } 
    }
```

Lo que quiero hacer es **imprimir los datos de todos los empleados junto con todos los numeros de emergencia que correspondan a ese empleado**. Como se ve en el modelo de empleado, tengo un método con el que hago la consulta y al momento de imprimir con `dd($empleado)` me trae lo siguiente:

- Si tengo el empleado `id = 1` y este tiene dos registros de emergencias, me imprime dos arreglos, cada uno con el id de emplead pero igual cada uno con un registro diferente de emegercia.

lo que busco es **que me imprima un solo arreglo** con el `id = 1` y dentro de este, un arreglo con todos los registros de emergencia que se tengan.

Aqui les dejo unas capturas de como estoy recibiendo el arreglo, no me dejaba poner la imagen completa asi que solo puse donde se imprimen los datos de emergencia.

[image: IMG]
[image: IMG]

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Comment: No termino de entender. Se supone que cada empleado tendría un arreglo de contactos de emergencia y cada contacto trae toda la información que necesitas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent hace eso por ti. si quieres todos los empleados con sus emergencias solo debes escribir:

```
$empleados= Valach\Empleado::with('emergencias')->get();
```

un solo empleado seria:

```
$empleado= Valach\Empleado::findOrFail(1);
$empleado = $empleado->load('emergencias');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funcione de esta manera.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza "with" o "load".

```
$Empleados = Valach\Empleado::with('emergencias');
```

o puedes utilizar:

```
$Empleados = Valach\Empleado::all();
$Empleados = $Empleados->load('emergencias');
```